# Android Widget : Dynamic colors not updating

Tags: android, android-widget, glance-appwidget, material-you

When switching Color Palette from the Android Theme page, I think there is a system bug :

- all the 4 first colors are applied without errors
- but all the colors of the next pages fallback to the colors of the first page totally ignoring what I selected (mostly visible when I select the middle RED theme)

[image]

Is this a bug ?

In the video you can also see that :

- system widgets (clock) have this bug
- my custom widget have this bug (Android Glance@beta01 widget using `@android:color/system_accent1_200` like colors)
- polychromatic icons (Android 13) doest NOT have this bug

I first though that my widget or Glance were the issue, but seems not.

Any thougts on this ?

Comment: Glance does not support recomposition , i believe. Probably, why this should be happening